# Pass component template and functions while opening an expanded view in material dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-dialog

I am trying to create components following DRY coding principles but I am stuck with a certain use case. I have a requirement to open an expanded view of a component in a dialog box. The component shows JSON records in a list format with pagination. PFB image:

[image: Component snap]

As you can see there is an expand button(top right corner) which expands the component to a dialog box and shows records in a tablular format. PFB image:

[image: Dialog snap]

Currently I have copied all the functions and template of the base component to the dialog component to make it work but it openly violates DRY principles and also a bad practice. I also need to keep both the components in sync with each other like the filters should be passed to both the components, etc.

Comment: Can you provide some kind of code snippet? I think it would be helpful to understand what you've done and how it needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

How about a shared service? You put your logic there and then the components  are controlling how output is displayed.

Or

Parent component controls how the table component displayed in a div with the selector or if it is opened in the dialog via dialog.open(YourTableComponent,...)